# I accidentally deleted IIS Express on my Documents folder

Tags: iis, webmatrix

I deleted the IIS Express folder by mistake, now WebMatrix doesn't work.
The only solution I found online is to open `cmd.exe` and redirect IIS to another folder to force automated creation:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress /userhome:C:\MyDocs\IISExpress
```

where `C:\MyDocs` is the new root location for your Documents folder.

When I try to use `cmd.exe` as suggested I get this response `"The filename, Directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"`. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: what are you typing into the command prompt?

Comment: This is what I type "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress /userhome:C:\MyDocs\IISExpress"

Comment: even in 2015 the iisexpress is not mature enough. If we use node it is just so simple. The IISexpress is too dependent on OS and configuration

Comment: if your path has spaces, you have to use double quote: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress /userhome:"C:\users\yourusername\My Documents\IISExpress"